# XMLHttpRequest returns always undefined in IE9

Tags: php, ajax, internet-explorer, jquery

i would want to know for what reason this code works on firefox, chrome and IE10, but not in IE9

```
var ajaxReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
var params = "name="+$('#name').val()
var url = "register.php";

ajaxReq.open("POST", url, true);                               

ajaxReq.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");    
ajaxReq.setRequestHeader("Content-length",params.length);
ajaxReq.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close"); 

ajaxReq.onreadystatechange = function(){
 if(ajaxReq.readyState == 4 && ajaxReq.status == 200) 
{alert(ajaxReq.response)} //<---this results undefined

 }
```

The code contained in php file itself doesn't matters because for do some proofs i rent it very minimal:

```
header('Content-Type: text/json');
echo 'response';
exit;
```

Comment: Instead of `.response`, it should be `.responseText` or `.responseXML` - see [HTTP response](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest#The_HTTP_response)

Comment: wow it's worked! But can i use responseText in case i will receive JSON encode objects?

Comment: Yes, as `JSON` is a _plain text_ format. I added this as an answer with a longer description.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `.response`, it should be `.responseText` or `.responseXML` - see [HTTP response](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest#The_HTTP_response). In your case, I assume that changing to `alert(ajaxReq.responseText);` will fix it.

`response` is not a property of the XMLHttpRequest object, which is why the JavaScript engine is throwing an `undefined` error.

From the aforementioned documentation:

> responseText will contain the response of the server in plain text by a conforming user agent

so use `responseText` for everything in plain text apart from `XML`, which includes `JSON`, as that is a *plain text* format.